# Suggestions database table with xml files. (mysql/php)

Tags: php, mysql, database, wordpress

I am looking for some suggestions on how to design the database and if it is possible to do what I want. I am trying to get a xml into a database table by a uploading form. The table should handle  more than 1 xml file. The concents should remain inside the file but should also be able to read (display on page). (e.g select the xmlfile you desire and display the contents of that file)

Is this even possible or do I have to upload the xml's content in a table (e.g  ) to be able to display it on a webpage?

I hope someone can help me out with this one.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself?

Comment: *forgot, I have used a plugin (visual form builder) that had a upload function, but the problem with that one was that the xml files that were uploaded for some reason all had the same data, so a xml file 1 and xml file 2 had the same data while the content was different. That table had 1 field that was named data by the way.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you are trying to achieve here but you will need to build a schema that matches xml structure.

And is you ask why? You might need to filter results in future and using xml files to filter results is tiresome

Let us know if you need help designing schema!

Comment: Thanks, I can design it myself but I was not sure if I should make a table that has the same fields as the content of the xml or that I just "stored" the file itself in the database and display the contents of that file whenever I called it.

Comment: Well, I decided too fast hehe, one little question. If I have the following xml: <profile><firstname></firstname><lastname></lastname></profile>, do I also make a field for profiles, or only firstname and lastname?

Comment: @NiekJonkman For your question about whether you should make a table or store file itself, it really depends.

If your xml has a standard structure, best option is to go for tables.

This is because you might need to filter the fields later on and as i said sing xml files to filter results is tiresome. I'd say it's a nightmare for performance.

And for your second question better create a table profiles, which has columns first name, last name columns etc. This is the recommended way.

Comment: Allright, thanks for that I'll try it out and see if I can get it to work ;)

Comment: Ok, great! good luck, please +1 if you found the answer. Thanks

Comment: I have a too low rep but whenever I get the required reputation points I'll +1 on you :)